# shell scripting, how to run different code based on selection?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, ksh, aix

I have a shell script as below...

```
#!/bin/ksh

set_logging() {
if [ -f "$LOG_FILE" ]
then
  mv $LOG_FILE $LOG_FILE.$SYNCDATE
else
  touch $LOG_FILE
fi
# set logging for stdout and stderr (run this if user selects start)
exec >> $LOG_FILE
exec 2>&1

# run this if user selects dry
#exec something else
#exec something else

}

set_logging

# menu
if [[ ! -n $1 ]] ; then
  clear
  echo ""
  echo "What are you trying to do?"
  echo "start"
  echo "dry"
  echo "help"
  echo ""
  exit 99
fi

case "$1" in
  start)    run_tar;;
  dry)  nothing_here_yet;;
  help) print_help;;
  *) clear
echo "Your syntax is incorrect!"; exit 99;;
esac
```

This is a snipped of the actual script, running on AIX 7.1 UNIX OS.

What I am trying to do is based on user selection on the menu, change what parts get executed within the set_logging() block (you'll notice I commented the code I want to run if user selects different menu option just to help this example).

Again, this is an example to keep it simple so I understand and can use it in different parts of my shell script.

Anyone able to help?

Comment: You already know how to do different things based on the value of a variable. You use it at the bottom of that snippet. Just apply that to inside `set_logging`. You'll also need to pass `"$1"` to the function.

Comment: @EtanReisner I think thats the answer he is expecting , could you post it in answer section to

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally clear of some details.  If you put the following code at the top where the comments are, then it won't really work because $1 might not be set.  It needs to go after the test if $1 is empty.  For what you describe, you don't need something as complex as a case statement.  You can do it with an if statement like:

```
if [[ "$1" = "dry" ]] ; then
  exec something
  exec somethingelse
fi
```

You want the $1 inside quotes.  Otherwise, if it is not set, $1 disappears entirely and the statement becomes invalid.  Likewise with the if test that you have, you should put the $1 inside double quotes.

You can use = or == depending upon lots of factors.  Generally = and == are equivalent with a few exceptions (e.g. very old bourne shell does not have ==, etc.)

Last `[[ ! -n $1 ]]` is probably better written `[[ -z "$1" ]]`

Comment: `[[` does not have the empty argument problems that `[` has as it is syntactic and not a command.

Comment: thanks.  I will probably keep enclosing shell variables in double quotes.  I use a lot of languages and different platforms.  If I find something that works everywhere, I use it.  That allows me to not try and remember all the special cases in all the languages on all the platforms.  Actually.  I tend to do "${x}" everywhere but I thought that would not add to this user's understanding.  Thanks again.